# Automate semantic UI dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, semantic-ui

How to automate semantic `UI dropdown` in selenium using Java.

It is not working with this code:

```
Select drpdwn1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ddIssue")));
int sel1Size = drpdwn1.getOptions().size();
for (int i = 0; i < sel1Size; i++) {
  drpdwn1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ddIssue")));
  drpdwn1.selectByIndex(i);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ticketMessage\"]")).sendKeys(" test");
}
```

The DOM HTML code is-

```
<div class="ui fluid dropdown search selection active visible">
<select id="ddIssue" name="IssueTypeId">
 <option value="">SelectIssueType</option>
 <option value="12">test isssue type</option>
 <option value="13">Test</option>
 <option value="14">tester</option>
</select>
 <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
 <input class="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">
  <div class="default text">SelectIssueType</div>
  <div class="menu transition visible" tabindex="-1" style="display: block !important;">
    <div class="item" data-value="12">test isssue type</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="13">Test</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="14">tester</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: Selecting value from dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code to select "Test" value from your dropdown:**

```
 Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("IssueTypeId")));

    List <WebElement> count= drpCountry.getOptions();
    int size= count.size();

    for(int i =0; i<size ; i++){
            String value = count.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(value);
            drpCountry.selectByIndex(i);
        }
```

Comment: I have multiple values in ddl, and the goal is to automate them all, not specific one

Answer (score 0):

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("IssueTypeId")));
        List<WebElement> oSize = oSelect.getOptions();
        int iListSize = oSize.size();
        // Setting up the loop to print all the options
        for(int i =0; i < iListSize ; i++){
            // Storing the value of the option  
            String sValue = oSelect.getOptions().get(i).getText();
            // Printing the stored value
            System.out.println(sValue);
            oSelect.selectByIndex(i);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dd= new Select(driver.findElementById("ddIssue"); 

//storing the WebElements in a list
List<WebElement> allOptions=dd.getOptions();

//getting the count
int count=allOptions.size();

//printing the count
S.O.P(count);

//looping it and printing the each text value in the dropdown
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){

String ddValues=allOptions.get(i).getText();

S.O.P(ddValues);

//selecting each of the drop down values
dd.selectByIndex(i);

}
```

If suppose this doesn't work then post the error or exception you have got.

Comment: I am getting following error-

 element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Comment: Then in that case trying using explicit wait statement.

Comment: Even in that case, it is not working.It is only iterating once.

Comment: whats the count of the drop down values?Can you share a screenshot for reference

Comment: Count of dropdown values is 7.